# Flutter achieve grouped row table/datatable

Tags: flutter

Flutter users.
I need a help with achieving a table/datatable like this (Img is shown in [imgur.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CaARI.jpg)).
I cannot figure out how to get grouped row. Ex: May 2nd => 3 rows separate in Shifts!
[Link to the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CaARI.jpg)

Comment: I'd like to do something similar with weekly grouping.  Have you had any luck finding an answer yet?

Comment: I was keeping it delayed until now, but I am thinking of using https://pluto.weblaze.dev/row-grouping.
I am already using pluto_grid, but I missed this feature. So you can try as well.
Hope it helps!